# Puppet Error: Could not open downloaded file

Tags: puppet

**Edit:** Content of class filebeat::install_filebeat added.

I have 2 classes in my puppet module, *class filebeat* and *class filebeat::install_filebeat inherits filebeat*.

In class filebeat I want to download a properties file and save it in an specific path so I do:

```
exec{ 'get_properties_file':
command => "/usr/bin/curl -o ${properties_path} '${download_url}'",
creates => $properties_path,
}

file{ $properties_path:
mode    => '644',
target  => $properties_path 
require => Exec["get_properties file"],
}
```

This is working fine, and the file is downloaded to the $properties_path

Then in my class filebeat::install_filebeat I have:

```
class filebeat::install_filebeat inherits filebeat{

  $file = file($properties_path)
  $file = file($properties_path)
  $properties_lines = split( $file, '\r')
  $host_line = grep($properties_lines, '^host=.*')
  $token_line = grep($properties_lines, '^token=.*')
  $host_splited = split($host_line[0], '=')
  $token_splited = split($token_line[0], '=')
  $token = join(delete_at($token_splited,0),"=")
  $host = join(delete_at($host_splited,0),"=")

  file { '/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml':
    ensure  => 'present',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '644',
    purge   => true,
    content => template("filebeat/${filebeat_template}"),
  }

  service { 'filebeat':
    ensure     => running,
    enable     => true,
    hasstatus  => true,
    hasrestart => true,
 }

File['/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml'] -> Service['filebeat'] 
}
```

This works fine if the file has been saved in the $properties_path in a previous execution but when I try to do everything at once by adding in my class filebeat 
       include filebeat::install_filebeat

I keep getting the error: 
"**Error: Could not find any files from [properties_path]**"

It seems to me that puppet is trying to do file($properties_path) before doing the download first, but I really don't how to solve it..

Any help will be awsome!

Comment: Is this Puppet with or without using the agent?

Comment: Without agent, I don't have a master, only running it locally

Comment: Ok then you only have one problem here, which is that the function is executed during catalog compilation, but the file in the argument to the function does not exist until catalog execution. You are going to have to solve this another way.

Comment: But for example when I am dowloanding a pakage I can install it and start the service in the same catalogue running.. Is not a change to do that with my file? How can I just tell the function that the resource file is needed before?

Comment: Ok, sorry if I didn't understood it, didn't mean to bother you

Comment: You weren't being bothering. If you want help figuring this out, I would recommend putting the contents of `filebeat::install_filebeat` in your question so we can determine another method of solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I just added it to the question